# How to insert log into Oracle SQL from C#?

Tags: c#, oracle, c#-4.0, oledb, c#-3.0

How to insert log into Oracle SQL?

I tried this code but get an error

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

Code:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();

connection.Open();
//string sql = @"insert into IA_RptLog(jobname)values('testcronjob')";
string sql = @"insert into insert_log (jobstatus, jobsvr, jobname, sessionid)
               values('Start', 'SHDB10G', 'testcronjob', '12345')";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql,connection);
connection.Close();
```

Comment: where is the connection string?

Comment: how to create connection string?

Comment: A quick google search of "c# oledb connection string" provides many examples such as - https://www.connectionstrings.com/net-framework-data-provider-for-ole-db/ .  Please try to do a bit of research before posting a question.  thanks.

Comment: You would need to include the connection string to your SQL database. Otherwise, your code has no idea what it is you're trying to access.

Comment: @wayne: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question was very basic, so before asking please investigate some time in the future to look for available tutorials.